# Views page access callback

Tags: views

How can I change the access callback for a page view (Views module)? I tried `hook_menu_alter` but realized that views uses the same hook to add the menu items defined by it - as a result of which, I am unable to have access to them.

Any way out?

Comment: This is an interesting one http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/advanced-drupal-views-access-control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Views allows you to set the acess within the UI, you can restrict based on roles or permission.

Usually that should be enought but if you need to set a custom access callback you can use hook_menu_alter but you will also need to make sure your module is called after the views hook_menu_alter, you can change the weight of your module in the database or you can use hook_module_implements_alter to make sure your module is called after the views module for the menu alter hook.

Comment: Sweet. hook_module_implements_alter is a good way out but it would be awesome if there was a lighter solution. Problem right now is that custom access functions in Views can take only static arguments.

Comment: Thank you for this example, here is a detailed example of some of this code in action for this problem: http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-create-menu-tab-views-node-content-type

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Views Access Callback](http://drupal.org/project/views_access_callback) module.

> Provides callback-based access control for Views.
>
> Available callback functions are defined by modules using `hook_views_access_callbacks()` function (in the same way as in `hook_perm()`), then could be set in the view's "Access restrictions" configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - the views_access_callback module is very useful, and it automatically passes any arguments your view has to the callback. It's easier than writing a Views plugin. It's cleaner than writing a hook_menu_alter() in a module that needs to have its weight increased in the system table (hook_module_implements_alter doesn't exist in D6)

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly answer that question, but you do have two options.

You can make a custom block and embed the view in it, and then hook_menu it into the system with access control.

The other option is to use a panel page, and add the view to a pane.  You can then control access via the panels interface.